# Placing 8 identical rooks on the chessboard so that none of them attacks each other and none of them occupies the long diagonal

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we place $8$ identical rooks on a chessboard so that none of them attacks each other and none of them stands on the long diagonal A1 - H8?

I thought about the inclusion-exclusion principle, however, it is hard to determine how many possible movements each of these rooks will have - it depends on the choice of the one to rearrange. 
Also, I made some observations on the chessboard and noticed that it is not possible to have an odd number of rooks out of the long diagonal whereas the rest of them occupy it - it may be of some help to the inclusion-exclusion but I can't link it together. 
 
Any hints will be most appreciated.

Comment: We know there is at least one.  Divide the board into four 4×4 quadrants.  On the upper left quadrant place four rooks along the diagonal from (1,4) to (4,1).  On the lower right use the same pattern for the remaining rooks.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement.

Comment: Would it be enough to calculate the number of derangements of $8$ elements?

Comment: That's what it is!

Comment: You don't mention the other long diagonal (a8-h1).  Is it off-limits too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the set of possibilities to place the rooks on the board in such a way that none of them attacks another.

For $L\in\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}$ let $L$ denote the subset of possibilities characterized by a rook on diagonal $A1-H8$ in row $L$.

Then to be found is:$$|A^{\complement}\cap\cdots\cap H^{\complement}|=|T|-|A\cup\cdots\cup H|=8!-|A\cup\cdots\cup H|$$

Then inclusion/exclusion and symmetry come in and the cardinality of an intersection of $k$ distinct elements from $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}$ is $(8-k)!$.

This leads to:$$8!-|A\cup\cdots\cup H|=\sum_{k=0}^{8}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{8}{k}\left(8-k\right)!=14833$$possibilities.

Comment: Is the correct answer not 14833?

Comment: Have you reasons to believe that it is 14833 then? I have not the guts yet to exclude that something is wrong in my answer. Ah wait, I think I made a mistake with calculation. Repaired now.

Comment: Because as @Oscar Lanzi mentioned in one of the above comments, the number we are looking for is in the same time the number of derangements of $8$ elements, which is 14833

Comment: Yes, the formula looks familiar to me. It indeed calculates the number of derangements. I have to go now and will be back later.

Answer (score 3):

Using Inclusion-Exclusion is one of the ways to approach this (and is good practice for inclusion-exclusion). Consider by the number of rooks that are on the diagonal.

Your total number of possibilities will be 8! (from here start excluding possibilities)

To see this consider that one rook will have to be placed in each row. For the first row you have 8 choices, for the second it can't go in the same column as the first so you have 7 choices and so on.

Try Inclusion-Exclusion from here and let me know if you need any more hints

Comment: This is a good answer, except you seem to have missed the “none on the long diagonal” bit. There are $7$ options for the first rook.

Comment: And after the 7 on the first row then depending on where you place it your second row has either 6 or 7 options (7 if the first was in column 2, 6 if it was in any other column) so it doesn't seem to even be trivial to adapt this technique.

Comment: @chris Place the rook in the column you just restricted, so if you place the first in row 3, place column 3 next. Only trouble is now when you place a piece in row 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: this method fails to account for what happens when you choose the top row for picks after the first (see the first comment). It needs some adaptation.

A trick for approaching this:

- Place the first rook anywhere in the first column other than on the main diagonal. 7 choices.
- Go over on the row from your first choice to the main diagonal. Place the 2nd rook on that column. There are still 7 choices.
- Go over on the row from the 2nd rook to the main diagonal, and place the third rook in that column. Now there are 6 choices, as the first rook restricts a spot on this column.

Continue with this, always placing new rooks on the column where the previous rook attacks the main diagonal. Each new rook will have 1 few places available than the one before. Thus there will be $7\cdot 7! = 35280$ ways it can be done.

Comment: So for the first column I place the rook in row 2. So I place the 2nd column next. I have 7 options. I choose to place it on row 1. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Chris, in that case you'd place the 3rd column, and you'd have 5 choices.  We'll have to flesh this one out a bit better.

Comment: @Chris - true. I wrote this quickly during my lunch break, and while I saw that this method would not lead you to other already-chosen columns, I missed noting that the reason did not apply to column 1. But as Monty Harder points out, this can be worked around.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that if you did the 2nd and then 1st then you are effectively left with a 6x6 version of the original problem. Wasn't sure if you could create some kind of recurrence using this. It started doing my head in at this point though. :)